# How do you close an undecorated preview window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

I made a new dialog window in Eclipse using the Window layout gui editor. I set the window as undecorated, and as a modal dialog. I clicked Preview, which works, but now I can't figure out how to close the window as it is undecorated. I cannot seem to access Eclipse until the window is closed. Is there a key command that does this?

CTRL SHFT ESC reveals no unique process (as far as I can tell) for this window, and I'd rather not force close Eclipse right now if I don't have to (lots of unsaved changes).

Answer (score 0):

It's an old Question, but in case anyone comes up with the same Problem, just like I did, **ALT + F4** is the Solution.